# WPF Slider VisualStateManager

Tags: wpf, slider, visualstatemanager, pressed

I'm trying to do my own Slider Style in XAML, but i don't get it quite right. The `VisualState x:Name="Pressed"` is not being triggered.

```
...
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Slider">
    <Grid>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState Name="Normal" />
                <VisualState Name="MouseOver">
                    ...
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState Name="Pressed">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RepeatButtonValueBrush" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="{StaticResource PressedValueColor}" Duration="0"/>
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RepeatButtonRestBrush" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="{StaticResource PressedTrackColor}" Duration="0"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState Name="Disabled">
                    ...
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        ...
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `VisualStateManager.GoToState` method to change visual states. See this [VisualStateManager and Triggers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2009/02/27/the-visualstatemanager-and-triggers.aspx) article.

Comment: Could you please post an example? Thanks!

Comment: I posted a link to an article with multiple examples.